# Plugin performance issues with tailable collections and enumerators

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I have created a simple Play plugin that creates user notifications.
This is done by using a tailable, capable collection.

```
lazy val unprocessed: Future[Enumerator[Event]] = {

  for {
    coll <- collection
  } yield coll.find(Json.obj("processed" -> false))
      .options(QueryOpts().tailable.awaitData)
      .cursor[Event]
      .enumerate()
}
```

The plugin starts at application start and uses an Iteratee with this Enumerator

```
val itr = Iteratee.foreach[Event](e => {
    // Intentionally left empty for now 
})
EventDao.unprozessed map(_.apply(itr))
```

Whith this code all requests - also those that don't touch the collections/Enumerators used here will respond at least 5x slower than before.
I already tried to move those two segments above into a new execution context but this didn't help.
As soon as I comment out `EventDao.unprozessed` the speed is back to normal. So it seems as if the runtime gets occupied watching the tailable collection.

What is happening here behind the scenes?

Comment: What is the type of `collection`?

Comment: It is a `Future[JSONCollection]`
Meanwhile I found this https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/issues/75 which exactly describes my problem also. So it seems as if it is a bug.